# SASS - Accessing Multidimensional Array's Value

Tags: css, sass

I'm new at SASS. I created a multidimensional array, like this:

```
$content: (
    width: 100%,
    content-header: (
        width: 320px
    ),
    content-main: (
        width: 100%
    ),
    content-footer: (
        width: 320px
    )
);
```

How can i access directly nested array value?

I want to access `$content-main[width]`. How can i access?

Comment: Why and when do you want to access it? I mean in your scss, html, php, js....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this considerably harder than it needs to be. Arrays are useful if you need to loop over variables, you would need to make your own sass function for this which uses `map-get`. I strongly recommend just using namespaced variables which are simpler and more portable e.g. `$content-width` `$content-main-width`.

If you really want to do it see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/

```
/// Map deep get
/// @author Hugo Giraudel
/// @access public
/// @param {Map} $map - Map
/// @param {Arglist} $keys - Key chain
/// @return {*} - Desired value
@function map-deep-get($map, $keys...) {
    @each $key in $keys {
        $map: map-get($map, $key);
    }
    @return $map;
}

map-deep-get($content, "content-header", "width");
```

Answer (score 0):

https://sass-lang.su/documentation/modules/map

```
map.get($content, "content-main", "width");
```